# Wrap a highlighted string in custom text in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, macros, word-wrap, shortcut

An example:

I'm sick of writing `$log.debug(myWord);`

Is there any way in VSCode I can double click `myWord` to highlight it and hit a binded key or run a command that inserts `$log.debug(` before and `);` after?

Comment: insert a snippet with a keybinding using the selected text variable `TM_SELECTED_TEXT`

Comment: @rioV8 Hi, thanks for this - I've figured it out due to your `TM_SELECTED_TEXT` hint.

Comment: @MattGarnett It would be nice if you could share your found solution as an answer to the question, so that other people could benefit from your discovery.

Comment: @Pharap Sorted!

Comment: Thanks for asking this! This is the top Google result for the search "highlight text in vscode and wrap with character".

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by opening up "Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)" via ctrl+shift+p and adding the following item:

```
[
    {
        "key": "alt+shift+e",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
            "snippet": "\\$log.error(\"${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}\", $TM_SELECTED_TEXT$1);"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box and in addition to what you are looking for: You can select some text or multiple lines of text and while it is highlighted press one of the following characters to have it wrapped with the character plus the corresponding closing character. Please edit this answer if you know of any others:

- (
- [
- {
- `

I don't know what this feature is called, if I did we might be able to find the VSCode docs and link them here.